# How To Open Modal Dialog To External Website in Dynamics CRM?

Tags: dynamics-crm, xss, dynamics-crm-online

I have an external website that I'm using for payment processing.  I'd like to create a modal dialog on the Lead Form that allows the user to process payment.  I'm currently using [Alert.js](https://alertjs.codeplex.com/) to create the modal, but it is failing to load with a Cross Site Scripting Error:

> DOMException: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from
>   'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin
>   "https://MyCrmOnlineOrg.crm.dynamics.com" from accessing a
>   cross-origin frame.

The interesting thing is I can actually debug the javascript on the external page (it gets downloaded and executes withing the F12 developer tools), but after I get the error, the "Loading" Gif never goes away...

I can get it to load correctly as an IFrame, as long as I uncheck the "Restrict cross-frame scripting, where supported" checkbox. Is there someway to do that for the Alert.js modal call?  Is there a different way to do that?

Comment: Have you tried wrapping your external page in an html web resource with an iframe in CRM and then to open the web resource with the alert.js?

Comment: @BojanBorisovski I thought about trying this, the only problem is that the "Restrict cross-frame scripting, where supported" checkbox, is per iFrame on the form, not for the webresource, so I don't see that as helping anything.

Comment: The "Restrict cross-frame scripting, where supported" checkbox, simply prevents scripts executing in the page put in the iframe, if you had it checked than javascript on that page when loaded on your form will not run.

For example i iframed once a page which was firing a print event. That check box prevented it.

If you put it in a html web resource through an iframe, that check box would not matter, as you will have control on how you would like to embed that page on your web resource.

Comment: @BojanBorisovski The Javascript runs, but I the loading gif never goes away.  See updated to question

Comment: i believe that error is thrown when trying to access an element in the page, in this case the Document object, the browser considers this as an XSS and doesn't allow it.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to the Restrict tick box for XSS issues would be :

- 1) [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)
- 2) [HTML5 MessageChannel](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/MessageChannel)

1 is good if your external site is a web service you could call from a JS web resource, which is not the case. 2 doesn't require a web service, it is cross-document messaging technique but it requires that you can edit the external's web site JS code, as it has to allow a request from your domain.

Comment: Hi Jordi!  I setup a website that had CORS Enabled for accessing our CRM Environment, and that was futile, which after, re-reading your answer, you said wouldn't  work.  I'm not sure how the HTML5 MessageChannel will work from CRM.  Would you have a simple example?